# Re-order an array by splitting it in 2 and add the first part to the end

Tags: php, arrays, split

I want to split an array in 2 pieces and add the first slice to the end. The point where it should splitten is set in another variable.

```
$where = 7;
$array = array( 1 => "aaa", 2 => "bbb", 7 => "ccc", 13 => "ddd", 20 => "eee" );

//...code...
//I'd like to have

$array = array(7 => "ccc", 13 => "ddd", 20 => "eee", 1 => "aaa", 2 => "bbb" );
```

How to achieve that?

Comment: Are the keys 3, 4, ... etc really missing or did you just omit them to make it shorter?

Comment: Really missing :) It's an array in ascending order but it doesn't have always all the keys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
foreach($array as $key=>$value)
{
    if ($key === $where)
    {
        break;
    }

    unset($array[$key]);
    $array[$key] = $value;
}
```

Comment: Why loop through the whole array?

Comment: Honestly, I never thought of it. Editing.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [array_slice()](http://php.net/manual/de/function.array-slice.php) to split the array twice -->

```
$arr1 = array_slice($array, 0, $where-1);
$arr2 = array_slice($array, $where, count($array)-1);
$array = array();
$array[] = $arr2;
$array[] = $arr1;
```

Comment: The second parameter to `array_slice()` is an *offset*, not an *index* (and the third is a *length*).

Comment: array_slice will rearrange the array indexes, which have to be kept intact.

Comment: @Summoner, that's okay since you can tell `array_slice()` to preserve them.

Comment: Sorry. Then array_slice wouldn't work as easy as the for-loop above.

@salathe
offset is the startindex
but the third argument must of course be the length... I should read more carefully the php-doc.

Answer (score 1):

```
function split_array($array, $where) {
    $temp_array = array();
    foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
         if($key != $where) {
               $temp_array[$key] = $value;
               unset($array[$key]);
         }
         else {
               break;
         }
    }
    //return array_merge($array, $temp_array);
    return ($array+$temp_array);
}
```

Comment: array_merge doesn't keep the numeric keys of an array.

Comment: @Summoner what about use $array+$temp_array directly?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`array_slice()`](http://php.net/array_slice) with a *offset* to split the array, and join the two chunks with the array union operator.

```
$where = 7;
$array = array( 1 => "aaa", 2 => "bbb", 7 => "ccc", 13 => "ddd", 20 => "eee" );

$offset = array_search($where, array_keys($array), true);
if ($offset !== false) {
    $array = array_slice($array, $offset, null, true) + $array;
}
```